# simple Compass using Magnetometer - Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, sensors, compass, magnetometer

I am using **Sensortag CC2541** (connected to Nexus phone)

I am using the Magnetometer of this sensor to make a simple compass. I am using the following equations to find North, South, West, and East.

`Direction (y>0) = 90 - [arcTAN(x/y)]*180/pi`

`Direction (y<0) = 270 - [arcTAN(x/y)]*180/pi`

`Direction (y=0, x<0) = 180.0`

`Direction (y=0, x>0) = 0.0`

Here's the code i'm using in my **updateMagnetometer** method

```java
    @Override
    public void onUpdateMagnetometer(SensorTagManager mgr, Point3D b) {
        super.onUpdateMagnetometer(mgr, b);

        double m=0;

        if(b.x < 0.0 && (b.y < 0.01 && b.y > 0.0))
            m = 180;
        else if(b.x > 0.0 && (b.y < 0.01 && b.y > 0.0))
            m = 0;
        else if(b.y > 0.0)
            m = 90 - (Math.atan(b.x/b.y))*(180/Math.PI);
        else if(b.y < 0.0)
            m = 270 - (Math.atan(b.x/b.y))*(180/Math.PI);

        final float rot = (float) m;

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                pointer.setRotation(-rot); //pointer is the image of my compass
            }
        });
    }
```

But when I run it, the compass is always stuck between North and West NO MATTER how much I move, rotate, or change the position of the sensor.

Any mistakes I might be doing?

And also, I have looked a lot on the internet for making compass help. But I can't find anything. Any coding tips, pseudo code, or hint to make compass using magnetometer, accelerometer, and/or gyroscope???

---

**Extra info**

So this is in my main class. These methods are called every `x` seconds to update the readings.
PS: my sensor has 2 buttons (right and left)

```java
    mStManager.enableSensor(Sensor.MAGNETOMETER,MAGNETOMETER_UPDATE_PERIOD);
    mStManager.enableSensor(Sensor.ACCELEROMETER,MAGNETOMETER_UPDATE_PERIOD);    

    @Override
    public void onUpdateAmbientTemperature(SensorTagManager mgr, double temp) {
        super.onUpdateAmbientTemperature(mgr, temp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateAccelerometer(SensorTagManager mgr, Point3D acc) {
        super.onUpdateAccelerometer(mgr, acc);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateBarometer(SensorTagManager mgr, double pressure, double height) {
        super.onUpdateBarometer(mgr, pressure, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateGyroscope(SensorTagManager mgr, Point3D ang) {
        super.onUpdateGyroscope(mgr, ang);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateHumidity(SensorTagManager mgr, double rh) {
        super.onUpdateHumidity(mgr, rh);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateInfraredTemperature(SensorTagManager mgr, double temp) {
        super.onUpdateInfraredTemperature(mgr, temp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateKeys(SensorTagManager mgr, boolean left, boolean right) {
        super.onUpdateKeys(mgr, left, right);

        if (right) {
            mgr.calibrateMagnetometer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateMagnetometer(SensorTagManager mgr, Point3D b) {
        super.onUpdateMagnetometer(mgr, b);
    }

}
```

So basically in the `onUpdateMagnetometer` method, the `b` contains my reading. It is of class `Point3D` which is shown below

```java
public class Point3D {
public double x, y, z;

public Point3D(double x, double y, double z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}

public double norm() {
    return Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    long temp;
    temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(x);
    result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(y);
    result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(z);
    result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Point3D other = (Point3D) obj;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(x) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.x))
        return false;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(y) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.y))
        return false;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(z) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.z))
        return false;
    return true;
}

public String toString() {
    return "[" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ", " + this.z + "]";
}

}
```

Comment: I would love to help you but I really don't understand what your code is trying to do. First off, `Direction (y=0, x>0) = 0.0` is not an equation, I don't even know what that means. Second using one-letter variables is a great way to have people ignore your question since they are very hard to read. What is `b`? Does it contain some kind of reading from the magnetometer?

Comment: I got `Direction (y=0, x>0) = 0.0` from a website. It basically means if the magnetometer's `y` is equal to 0 and its `x` is bigger than 0, then the pointer of the compass must be at `0.0` (North). the rest are similar to his one. Also, `b` is the reading from magnetometer. In the argument, **b** is a of class `Point3D` which has `x, y, z` which are the variable of the magnetometer. Object `b` also contains methods such as `norm()`, `toString()`...etc... But the only and most important fields are `x,y,z`.

Comment: Right, I can see that `b` is a Point3D, that's in your code. My question is: what data is in it? are `x,y,z` describing a point on a unit circle, some sort of quaternion, strengths of the magnetic field in each axis, etc? You haven't given us enough of the code to know where the value of `b` is coming from.

Comment: I think I found the site you got those "equations" from...
http://aerospace.honeywell.com/~/media/Images/Plymouth%20Website%20PDFs/Magnetic%20Sensors/Application%20Notes/AN203_Compass_Heading_Using_Magnetometers.ashx
It's super weird that they only have arctan in two of the quadrants. Like that seems wrong.

Comment: that is indeed the website. And the xyz give the magnetic force vector

Comment: ok , then see my answer below.

Comment: I will soon give it a try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem you have is that you're handling the 3D magnetometer as a 2D sensor. It isn't.

One way to do this is to use data from both the magnetometer AND the accelerometer:

1. You capture a reading from both sensors, run those values through [SensorManager.getRotationMatrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix%28float[],%20float[],%20float[],%20float[]%29) to get an initial rotation matrix. (Note that in the documentation, the description of the matrices has the identity matrix and the rotation matrix switched.)
2. You put the result through [SensorManager.getOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float[],%20float[]%29) to get the device's orientation in 3D space
3. You use the first value in the orientation array as the compass direction

That final value represents the device's rotation around a vector pointed towards the center of the earth, which is exactly what you want for a compass. Using THAT value, you can then calculate the location of west, east, and south.

The code would look something like this: (ignoring the setup of the sensors)

```
// globals
private float[] gravityData = new float[3];
private float[] geomagneticData  = new float[3];
private boolean hasGravityData = false;
private boolean hasGeomagneticData = false;
private double rotationInDegrees;


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    switch (event.sensor.getType()){
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, gravityData, 0, 3);
            hasGravityData = true;
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, geomagneticData, 0, 3);
            hasGeomagneticData = true;
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    if (hasGravityData && hasGeomagneticData) {
        float identityMatrix[] = new float[9];
        float rotationMatrix[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, identityMatrix,
            gravityData, geomagneticData);

        if (success) {
            float orientationMatrix[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientationMatrix);
            float rotationInRadians = orientationMatrix[0];
            rotationInDegrees = Math.toDegrees(rotationInRadians);

            // do something with the rotation in degrees
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time. However, I believe your explanation and code uses the device's magnetometer and accelerometer. I am using a separate device (Sensortag cc2541). I have to get the magnetic field and acc from that device. And the device has the following. In both magnetometer AND Accelerometer, I can get an `x` `y` and `z`. Your code has functions and methods that my Sensor library probably doesn't have. **I have updated the question and added the methods and functions I have for Magnetometer and accelerometer**

Comment: Also, Doesn't this method need calibration? I mean from the code you've provided, it will automatically detect North?.

Comment: Looking at your updated question, I don't see any reason why you wouldn't be able to use the Android sensor library. The only difference is that my example uses arrays with the three data points (which is how Android natively supplies the sensor data) rather than your Point3D.

What you could do as a starting point is to implement this using the Nexus device's accelerometer/magnetometer, since this example does work. With that working then substitute in the data from the external device.

Comment: For calibration of the Nexus phone's built-in magnetometer, you just move the phone in a figure 8 allowing Android to calibrate it. Unfortunately I don't know how it would be done with your external device.